# How do I reduce .NET 6 single-file build sizes?

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I recently migrated one of my .NET Framework projects to .NET 6, from .NET Framework 4.8, and upon doing this I have noticed that no matter my build settings, what was once an 8.9MB program is now anywhere from 18.5-150MB. What settings can I change/what args can I use to reduce this? I want to keep it as a single .exe file

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/

Comment: correct answer was that converting to .NET core from .NET Framework added an extra "compatibility" library that added the extra space. thanks for linking documentation i already read though :)